# AWS data pipeline - pull data from external source?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to use an AWS data pipeline to pull data from an externally hosted MySQL datasource into an RDS MySQL instance.

Is this even possible? How can it be configured? I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

If it's not possible, is there any better option, or am I better to set up a manual push from the external server to the RDS instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at SqlDataNode?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-sqldatanode.html

This lets you provide a jdbc connection string to any MySql database.